# Some or more of something

Tags: meaning

I want to say "some 50 or more yards apart" (meaning at least 50 yards apart) but I'm not quite sure it's correct. I couldn't find the answer or an example of its use in google search.

However, I think I may have found the answer by typing "after some 20 or more years" which appears to be an equivalent example. Am I right in thinking so and are both phrases correct?

It's not easy to find examples on the web when there are precise figures involved. Indeed I had to search several times using different numbers an slightly different wording.

Comment: You've misunderstood this use of ***some***. It means ***about***, and tacking on ***or more*** doesn't alter the fact that 48 yards, for example, could still be referred to as *some 50 or more yards*.

Comment: Hello! :) Thank you for writing out a proper question.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+five+miles+or+more%2Csome+five+or+more+miles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20five%20miles%20or%20more%3B%2Cc0) for "some five miles or more,some five or more miles" seem to support my feeling that the terminal positioning of 'or more' is more idiomatic. But I'd be less than honest if I didn't mention that twice the distance seems to get people more confused about which sounds more natural.